# Threads inside Fragment

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments

I have an app using a Fragment with a View pager. I query the android contacts database (this should be fast) to get primary numbers of every contact to show in a ListView. The problem is, this seems to take some time. I tried to use a Thread and an ASyncTask inside onCreateView and "update" or set my adapter for my contact list. When I do this I'm getting some errors:

> can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

I tried using Looper.prepare() but it would still crash.

So I put in a handler, but there is a lag when people launch my app

```
final Runnable setupView = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            contactos  = con.getContactSearch("");
            setupContacts();
        }
    };
```

where:
getContactSearch:

```
public HashMap<String, ContactInfo> getContactSearch(String _where)
     {
         contactInfo = new HashMap<String, ContactInfo>();
         Cursor cursor = null ;
         if(_where.length()==0)
         {
            cursor = getContacts();
         }else
         {
             cursor = getContactsFilter(_where);
         }
         try
         {
         while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
              String id = cursor.getString(cursor
                      .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
              if(!contactInfo.containsKey(id))
              {

                  String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor
                          .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
                //obtenemos el telefono principal
                 //String number = "" ;//getPrimaryNumber(id);
                  ContactInfo ci = new ContactInfo(displayName,"",id);
                  contactInfo.put(id,ci);
              }
            }
            getPrimaryNumbers();


         }finally
         {
             cursor.close();
         }
         return contactInfo;
     }
```

and setupcontacts :

```
    mAdapter = new DialerContactsAdapter(contactos,getActivity());
        listaContactos.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        listaContactos.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        listaContactos.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                switch (scrollState) {
                case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                mAdapter.mBusy = false;
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
                case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL:
                    mAdapter.mBusy = false;
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
                case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING:
                    mAdapter.mBusy = true;
                break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

How I do this asynchronously? I'm wondering if I do only the searching of contacts in onCreate() what will happen, if its faster than onCreateView, the ListView will be null. Doing this "works" but there is a great lag.
How I can optimize this process?

Comment: Use `LoaderManager` to manage this. Fetching contacts within a loop will always be dead slow. If you're showing some info as a part of a ListView and other parts of the row are fetched faster than the contact information, I'd suggest you lazily load the slower parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setupContacts() method fiddles with UI stuff, which you cannot do outside the UI thread. You'll have to create a new Runnable and post it to the UI thread view Activity.runOnUiThread() or View.post().

If this seems like irritating boilerplate, it is. [AsyncTask](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html) was created with the intention to simplify this model of doing stuff in the background and then posting to the UI thread.

One problem with using AsyncTasks is that the Activity that started it may be dead by the time the task finishes. If it was a configuration change (e.g. device rotation), you'd still want the data, but the asynctask is pointing to a dead reference. At best nothing happens, at worst, you get a null pointer exception. This is really frustrating because Fragments can survive these configuration changes just fine.

[AnsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) was created to deal with this problem. The API documentation has an example of an AsyncTaskLoader that populates an Adapter after fetching some data.

Comment: Well my problem i guess was using CUrsorLoader, im using getcontentresolver now, perhaps i move all to Loader, and seems its a little faster now :) i use this site to use AsynTaskLoader because using Loader<D> was confusing this will help http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html